# Play2 Scalaで認証機能の主流は？

Tags: scala, playframework

playframework 2.x でのrailsのdeviseのような主流なものは何ですか？

Comment: PlayFramework で利用している言語は Java と Scala のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 利用している言語はscalaです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [SecureSocial](http://securesocial.ws/)
  最も有名で非常に高機能です。
  認可の機能は限定的です。
  ただし、Play2.3 に対応した stable 版がまだリリースされていません。
- [play2-auth](https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth/blob/master/README.ja.md)
  認証と認可の両方の機能を持ったシンプルなライブラリです。
  devise ほど高機能ではありません。
- [Deadbolt 2](http://deadbolt.ws/#/home)
  認証機能のライブラリです。
  Java用のライブラリでしたが現在ではScalaからも利用が可能になっています。

有名どころはこの3つでしょうか